# Cloud Endpoints - Is implementing JWT Possible?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoint

I'm working on a website and there is existing auth using Google cloud Datastore. I can't seem to find any documentation showing how I can generate a JSON web token compatible with cloud Endpoints for the end users.

Any links you can scavenge are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm working on a website and there is existing auth using Google cloud
>   Datastore.

If your current auth system is generating your own OAuth tokens, you cannot use those tokens with Google Cloud Endpoints. You must generate your tokens via Google mechanisms (Google Accounts). Otherwise, Google services cannot validate your tokens. Check to see if your backend is creating tokens or using Google OAuth to create tokens. However, there are three types of tokens: Access Token, Refresh Token, and Client ID Token. You backend may need to be modified to generate Client ID (OIDC) Tokens. Some systems just generate the first two.

The following assumes Google issued OAuth tokens.

Yes, it is possible and very easy. I will show you an example.

Note: I wrote an article on how to generate OAuth 2.0 Tokens with `CURL` including the Client ID token. [Google OAuth 2.0 – Testing with Curl – Refresh Access Token](https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl-refresh-access-token/) My article shows you the steps so that you can code in any language.

Using the CLI, generate an OAuth 2.0 Client ID Token:

```
gcloud config config-helper --format "value(credential.id_token)" --force-auth-refresh
```

Save the generated token. Call it TOKEN for this example.

URL is the endpoint URL.

Now make a request to your endpoint:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" URL
```

If you are curious to see what is inside the TOKEN JWT:

curl https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=TOKEN

The returned JSON will look like this:

```
{
  "aud": "https://cloudtask-abcdefabcdef-uc.a.run.app",
  "azp": "0123456789077420983142",
  "email": "cloudtask@development.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "email_verified": "true",
  "exp": "1559029789",
  "iat": "1559026189",
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "sub": "012345678901234567892",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789c3",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

> I can't seem to find any documentation showing how I can generate a
>   JSON web token compatible with cloud Endpoints for the end users.

Here is a link with details on Google Cloud Endpoints Authentication:

[Google ID token authentication](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authentication-method#google_id_token_authentication)

You may wonder why you cannot use your own tokens. The reason is that Google cannot verify the signature on the token.

OAuth tokens (Signed-JWT) are signed using a Private Key. They are validated using the Public Key. Google publishes the Public Keys at https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs

This allows Google and others to validate Google signed data. When you generate a token, Google cannot access your Public Key to validate the signature. Therefore, you must use Google generated tokens so that Google can validate them.

Comment: My application is from complete scratch. I dont want users to have to authenticate via google accounts as I have a list of users and hashed passwords. What do you think the best approach to move them over is?

Comment: The answer depends on the authentication platform. If your users will be using Gmail accounts, then they will have to create accounts. If you plan to use Google Identity Platform, then you can create accounts for them under your account.

Comment: Currently im just working with a list of usernames and passwords. We dont want to have to rely on OAUTH if possible or we want to make our own platform.

Comment: Then you cannot use authorization with Cloud Endpoints. You will need a different solution. I explained why in my answer. Which part is confusing?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [this](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-tools/tree/master/auth). You still need a Google service account, but only uses its private key to generate JWT.  ESP will validate it.